# ¿Cómo puedo traducir esta consulta utilizando LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola necesito saber como es posible "traducir" la siguiente consulta con LEFT JOINs o con otro método de agregación, ya que necesito obtener cosas como el nombre del departamento.

Tablas :

- Empleado (**rut**, nombre, salario, rutJefeDirecto, **codDepto**)
- Departamento (**codDepto**, nombre, presupuesto, rutJefeDepto)
- Proyecto (**codProyecto**, nombre, presupuesto, **codDeptoControla**, rutJefeProyecto)
- TrabajaEn (**rut**, **codProyecto**, cantHoras)
- LocalizacionDepto (**codDepto**, **localizacionD**)

La consulta en cuestión es esta

```
SELECT nombre
FROM empleado
WHERE rut IN (  SELECT rut
                FROM trabaja_en
                WHERE codProyecto IN (  SELECT codProyecto
                                        FROM proyecto
                                        WHERE codDeptoControla IN ( SELECT codDepto
                                                                    FROM departamento
                                                                    WHERE nombre = 'Investigacion')));
```

Comment: La consulta que muestras se resuelve naturalmente con un `inner join`, ¿por que preguntas por el `left join`?

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo las subconsultas que has escrito y utilizando [left join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html), puedes hacer:

```
SELECT
    e.nombre
FROM
    empleado e LEFT JOIN trabaja_en tr ON e.rut = tr.rut 
    LEFT JOIN proyecto pr ON tr.codProyecto = pr.codProyecto
    LEFT JOIN departamento dep ON pr.codDeptoControla = dep.codDepto
WHERE
    dep.nombre = 'Investigacion'
```